# How to limit the number of threads based on condition, without blocking the main one

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, queue

I want to limit the number of threads based on condition, without blocking the main one, because the main one is running a flask app.

The app has an endpoint that triggers some jobs in a sub-process, each one running in its own thread. At the end of the process, an entry is updated in the database. For the sake of simplicity let's assume that the command it's executing is just a plain `echo $something`. Partial code below:

```
# job_runner.py

import threading
import subprocess

def popen_with_callback(self, echo):
    """Run subprocess in a separate thread.

    starts subprocess in a separate thread --> adds new entry to the jobs table
    --> updates jobs.return_code on completion --> returns thread
    """
    def run_in_thread(echo):
        command = [
            "bash", "-c",
            "for ((i=0;i<100;i=i+1)); do echo %s; sleep 1; done" %(echo)
        ]
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            command,
            shell=False
        )

        # add job to database
        models.Job.create_job(proc.pid, ..., ...)
        proc.wait()

        # update job return code on exit
        models.Job.update_return_code(proc.returncode, ...)

    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_in_thread, args=(echo))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    return thread
```

Let's say my endpoint accepts just one argument, and based on that, it triggers `popen_with_callback` with that argument as param.

```
# some_view.py

from . import job_runner

@app.route('/run_job', methods=['POST'])
def run_job():
    data = request.get_json()
    echo = data['echo']
    job_runner.popen_with_callback(echo)
```

So this approach works fine, since the main thread continues to run the app and the jobs are triggered as threads that only run os processes so there is not heavy load on the application itself.

The problem is, that in reality some of the commands that are run are very CPU intensive ones and I would like to limit the concurrent threads when such job is invoked. So let's assume that the resource greedy one is called `i_use_cpu_like_crazy` and the others are `easy_peasy`.

I would like to limit the number of processes that use a lot of CPU to only one, without caring about the possible other, but I can't wrap my head around how to implement this kind of mechanism without blocking the main thread, maybe using `Queue`, `Pool`, `Semaphore`...

The idea is as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:5000/run_job -d '{"echo": "i_use_cpu_like_crazy"}'
```

1) if there is another process `i_use_cpu_like_crazy` already running, add this new one to a queue and trigger it when the running one finishes

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:5000/run_job -d '{"echo": "easy_peasy"}'
```

2) just create the thread and run the process without any checks